# Distribute p:menuitem list in menubar - safari

Tags: css, primefaces, safari

I am using the following CSS to horizontally distribute p:menuitem list in p:menubar. It perfectly works in chrome and firefox but not in Safari: the p:menuitem list is distributed vertically.

Any suggestion on how to make it work in Safari?
Thanks

```
div.menu{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.menu div.ui-menubar {
    text-align: center;
}
.menu .ui-menu-list{
    font-size: larger;
    font-style: italic;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-flex;
}
div.menu>ul.ui-menu-list>li>a{
    width: 100%;
}
div.menu>ul.ui-menu-list>li{
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-menuitem-text{
    float: none!important;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what's going wrong rather than expecting us to guess.

Comment: @Shaggy sorry ;(. Question updated.